# How to add or give Id and some Random number to that key(Id) in JSON in react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, object

My Data Look Like This =

```
[
  {"name":"Wooden Furniture"},
  {"name":"Office Furniture"},
  {"name":"Kitchen Furniture"},
  {"name":"Modular Office Furniture"}
]
```

I want To Convert It Into Like This =

```
[
  {"name":"Wooden Furniture","id":"someRandomNumber"},
  {"name":"Office Furniture","id":"someRandomNumber"},
  {"name":"Kitchen Furniture","id":"someRandomNumber"},
  {"name":"Modular Office Furniture","id":"someRandomNumber"}
]
```

I just wanted To add `Id:SomeRandomNumber` in each object

Comment: This has nothing to do with `react-native` or `json`.

Comment: What's the actual problem? Iterate over the elements in the object and add a new property.

Comment: `for (const item of data) item.id = Math.random()`

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [{"name":"Wooden Furniture"}, {"name":"Office Furniture"}, {"name":"Kitchen Furniture"}, {"name":"Modular Office Furniture"} ];

const res = arr.map(o => ({ ...o, id: "SomeRandomNumber" }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why does this deserve an answer? Such basic tasks as _"iterate over an array"_ and _"add a property to an object"_ is part of **every** JavaScript tutorial out there -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)